# Enviar e-mail anexando um arquivo local

Tags: php, email

Preciso de um script PHP que, ao ser executado, envia automaticamente um determinado arquivo local anexo em um email.

Não é formulário web preenchido pelo usuário. É envio automático quando o script for executado  sempre que alguém abrir a página.

Answer (score 5):

Podes fazer uso da classe [**PHPMailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para facilitar o envio do email.

Segue um exemplo de como podes atingir o que pretendes:

```
// Incluir a classe no teu ficheiro
require_once '/caminho/para/class.phpmailer.php';

// Instanciar a classe para envio de email
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Vamos tentar realizar o envio
try {

    // Remetente
    $mail->AddReplyTo('meunome@example.com', 'Meu Nome');
    $mail->SetFrom('meunome@example.com', 'Meu Nome');

    // Destinatário
    $mail->AddAddress('destinatario@example.com', 'Destinatário');

    // Assunto
    $mail->Subject = 'Segue ficheiro anexo com XPTO';

    // Mensagem para clientes de email sem suporte a HTML
    $mail->AltBody = 'Em anexo o ficheiro com XPTO.';

    // Mensagem para clientes de email com suporte a HTML
    $mail->MsgHTML('<p>Em anexo o ficheiro com XPTO.</p>');

    // Adicionar anexo
    $caminho = '/caminho/completo/para/ficheiro/';
    $ficheiro = 'anexo.pdf';

    $mail->AddAttachment($caminho.$ficheiro);

    // Enviar email
    $mail->Send();

    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    // Mensagens de erro do PHPMailer
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Outras mensagens de erro
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

O código em cima pode ser guardado dentro de um ficheiro PHP, por exemplo `enviaMail.php`, ficheiro esse que sempre que for chamado ou incluído num outro irá despoletar o envio do email.

Comment: Muito Bom! Vou testar. Eu imaginei algo assim, mas sem o conhecimento não tinha como, tanto que te pergunto se funciona só com PDF ou com qualquer arquivo?

Comment: Qualquer arquivo que queiras utilizar.

Comment: Estou fazendo as alterações para testar e me surge uma dúvida, não há referencia a porta, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Para envio regular não, mas com autenticação já precisas.

Comment: Tem como votar na sua resposta?

Comment: Tem, ao lado esquerdo da mesma, seta para cima (bom, dá reputação), seta para baixo (mau, tira reputação). Adicionalmente, o visto = marcar como resposta correta.

Comment: Recomendo a utilização de `require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'` em vez de `require_once 'class.phpmailer.php'`. :p

Comment: @Luciano você disse que `$mail->AddReplyTo('meunome@example.com', 'Meu Nome')` não roda, pode explicar exatamente como "não roda", emite algum erro, o script trava neste ponto, não está sendo adicionado ao email o `Reply-to:`? Seja claro por favor

Comment: fiz a alteração sugerida e ainda nada.

Comment: Apartir do $mail->AddReplyTo('meunome@example.com', 'Meu Nome') a página mostra como se não tivesse processado os comandos, apenas os mostrando como texto da página.

Comment: @Luciano O teu ficheiro tem que ter na primeira linha `<?php` e na última linha `?>`. Deverá também ter a extensão `.php`.

Comment: <HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>Primeiro exemplo</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

Comment: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Primeiro exemplo</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY>                                                                  <?php      Aqui o código    ?>    </BODY>

</HTML>

Comment: Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\envio_de_arquivo_automatico\PHP_ENVIAR_ARQUIVO_POR_EMAIL\aalgarismo.php on line 5

Comment: Warning: require_once(http://localhost/envio_de_arquivo_automatico/PHP ENVIAR ARQUIVO POR EMAIL/PHPMAILER/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\envio_de_arquivo_automatico\PHP_ENVIAR_ARQUIVO_POR_EMAIL\aalgarismo.php on line 5

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/envio_de_arquivo_automatico/PHP ENVIAR ARQUIVO POR EMAIL/PHPMAILER/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\envio_de_arquivo_automatico\PHP_ENVIAR_ARQUIVO_POR_EMAIL\aalgarismo.php on line 5

Comment: O script roda e aparece email enviado mas nada é enviado ao email cadastrado.

Comment: @Luciano O erro é bem básico, vou adicionou um incluiu o arquivo `class.phpmailer.php` de maneira errada, ele está apontando para o local erro, por isto da mensagem `Failed opening required`, corrija o caminho usado no `require_once` e provavelmente o script irá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

O PHP tem um função nativa chamada de mail, ela se encontra aqui no manual http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php , um pequeno detalhe é que tanto para usar a classe PHPMailer (já citado acima) como a função  nativa mail você precisa ter um servidor de email na sua máquina, caso contrário você terá um erro como resposta.